# Application startup difference eclipse and tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, deployment

When I develop my application I start it on a tomcat from within eclipse. Everyhing runs fine.

But when I deployed the `war` file to tomcat and use the startup.bat of tomcat, I'm constantly getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. This occurs during creating of Spring `@Bean` definitions. It also takes very much time to start at all.

Why is there obviously a difference between starting the app from eclipse and manually in tomcat? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Increase your heap memory and restart it.

Comment: How can I find out which memory settings eclipse is using? Because during dev it just works fine

Comment: Check your memory settings for JVM on both Eclipse and Tomcat. Should you need more specific answers please provide more insights about how you are actually starting both processes (Tomcat from Eclipse and stand alone Tomcat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set these vm arguments for tomcat,

```
-XX:PermSize<size> - Set initial PermGen Size.
-XX:MaxPermSize<size> - Set the maximum PermGen Size.
```

For more [info](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this] (http://www.jkstack.com/2012/12/how-to-set-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap.html)

There is no difference between starting the app from tomcat and eclipse. However it depends on various parameters like how many tomcat instances are running, any background huge memory consuming java apps running etc.

Answer (score -1):

Basically eclipse.ini has all the vm memory arguments set - like -Xms40m
-Xmx512m etc
The -Xms option sets the initial and minimum Java heap size. The Java heap (the “heap”) is the part of the memory where blocks of memory are allocated to objects and freed during garbage collection. - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

You might need to tweek the same for your tomcat.